# How to scrape protected email address with [at] and [dot] with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** protected email address with [at] and [dot] in python 3 and beautifulsoup 4
My code is here:

```
email = soup(text=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*'))

_emailtokens = str(email).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "").split(' ')

if len(_emailtokens):
    print([match.group(0) for token in _emailtokens for match in [re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", str(token.strip()))] if match])
```

**Output** of my code (every normal emails detected and **scraped** and introduced as output):

```
info@abcd.com
```

I need to **scrape** protected emails with below styles:

```
info [at] abcd.com
info@abcd [dot] com
info [at] abcd [dot] com
And etc.
```

I want to get all of this styles (change to normal style) like a normal email (e.g. info@abcd.com)

Comment: What is the current output of your code? What isn’t working?

Comment: Dear @AlexanderCécile, the output added to my question for you.

Comment: Which input does that output correspond to?

Comment: Dear @AlexanderCécile, this code is able to detect normal emails like info@abc.com and I need to add some protected styles (e.g. info [at] abc [dot] com) to detect as email and change to normal style after detection.

Comment: No one is not here to help me ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML which contains the address? Have you tried just doing a simple string replace “[at]”->”@“ and “[dot]->”.”?

Comment: Dear @AlexanderCécile, I need a regex like email = soup(text=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+ [@[at]] [A-Za-z0-9\._-]+ [\."[dot]"] + [a-zA-Z]*')) I want to work when we have @ or [at] and also when we have . or [dot] and all recombinations between this 4 states. I don't know how to write this regex.

Comment: Are you running the regex on the entirety of the page’s contents?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, is there any problem with this kind of regex usage?

Comment: Generally I would expect BeautifulSoup to be used to find the relevant HTML elements, and then regex on the contents only.

Answer (score 1):

First, the non-warranty statement: You will find on this website what purports to be regular expressions for validating email addresses (See [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)). They are *very* complicated. Needless to say, your basic regex would recognize a subset a valid email addresses, but we will go with that as the basis.  The basic regex now becomes:

```
r'[a-z0-9.+-]+(@|\s*\[\s*at\s*\]\s*)[a-za-z0-9._-]+(\.|\s*\[\s*dot\s*\]\s*)[a-z]*'
```

compiled with the `flag re.IGNORECASE` so that, for example, `at` or `AT` are equally recognized. This regex also allows flexible spacing as you will see in the following example code:

```
import re

emails = """info [at] abcd.com
info@abcd [dot] com
info [at] abcd [dot] com
INFO [ AT ] ABCD[ DOT ]COM"""

regex = re.compile(r'[a-z0-9.+-]+(@|\s*\[\s*at\s*\]\s*)[a-za-z0-9._-]+(\.|\s*\[\s*dot\s*\]\s*)[a-z]*', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
for m in regex.finditer(emails):
    print(m.group(0))
```

Prints:

```
info [at] abcd.com
info@abcd [dot] com
info [at] abcd [dot] com
INFO [ AT ] ABCD[ DOT ]COM
```